# Displaying current month unpaid customer in lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I have created 2 tables, Customer and Payment.
A customer can have many payments, where payment have payment date and amount.

Now I want to display current month's unpaid customer, I really couldn't figured it out how to create the query.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend going through the tutorials on the Lightswitch website for this. I believe there is a good example of something similar.

You can use the Customer data item to reference the Payments. Make sure there is a relationship over the tables. Then you can Edit Query from the left panel and choose Customer.Payment.'etc' as a parameter.

There are many more options from there, but this is a typical situation.